# How to catch javax.ws.rs.NotAllowedExeption?

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs

When I access my JAX-RS web service using GET and a path (i.e. http://localhost:8080/myservice/rest/report) that doesn't exist for GET, I run into the error `javax.ws.rs.NotAllowedExeption`.
How can I catch that?

My class looks like this:

```
@Path("/report")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class ReportResource {
    @GET
    @Path("/single/{reportId}")
    public Report getReport(@PathParam("reportId") String reportId) {
        System.out.println("GET Report single");
        return Mock.getReport(reportId);
    }

    ...

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an `ExceptionMapper` like this:

```
@Provider
public class NotAllowedMapper
     implements ExceptionMapper< NotAllowedExeption > {

   public Response toResponse(NotAllowedExeption e) {
      return Response.status(Response.Status.NOT_FOUND).build();
   }
}
```

Keep in mind that exists a nice exception hierarchy for various HTTP error conditions. You can check it here and other options to handler your exception.

https://dennis-xlc.gitbooks.io/restful-java-with-jax-rs-2-0-en/cn/part1/chapter7/exception_handling.html

Let me know if it works!

Comment: Nothing to add, exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!